# JS replace digits with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an identifiers of the elements, which look like this:

```
form_book_1_2_3
```

What I want is to replace second digit in this identifier with other value. I used function 'match' with the following regexp:

```
 var regexp = /\d_(\d)_\d/;
```

But it returns me array containing

```
[1_2_3, 2]
```

So, when I try to use function 'replace' it actually replace '1_2_3' string instead of only '2'. I don't understand how to point to the second matched element in the replace function. Or maybe my regexp is wrong?

Comment: that's expected. the first entry in your matched results is always the entire string that caused the match. your actual captured values start at position [1].

Comment: @MarcB ok, and how to tell "replace" function to work with value at position[1]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function will replace the entire matched string, not just a specific capture group. The easy solution is to capture the parts of the string that you *don't* want to modify and use them as references in the replacement pattern, for example:

```
"form_book_1_2_3".replace(/(\d)_\d_(\d)/, "$1_X_$2"); // "form_book_1_X_3"
```

For reference, the full syntax for replacement patterns is (from MDN):

> - `$$` — Inserts a "$".
> - `$&` — Inserts the matched substring.
> - `` $` `` — Inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring.
> - `$'`  — Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.
> - `$n` or `$nn` — Where *n* or *nn* are decimal digits, inserts the nth parenthesized submatch string, provided the first argument was a `RegExp` object.

Alternatively, you could use a function to accomplish the same goal, like this:

```
var replacer = function(match, a, b) { return a + "_X_" + b; };
"form_book_1_2_3".replace(/(\d)_\d_(\d)/, replacer); // "form_book_1_X_3"
```

Comment: Just a footnote: I thought "shouldn't that be `\1`?" [Looking it up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) proved me wrong.

Comment: Thanks for providing information about $ sign. Very helpful.