# How to do String replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, substring, indexof

I am making a web app, and in my admin side there's a functionality to add a dynamic input. The admin will enter a text into the `textarea` like:

```
'sample: _4_' | 'sample2: _some_'
```

What I want to achieve is that, I wanna replace the first `'` to `<p>` and the second `'` to `</p>` and when separator (`|`) meets, replace again the first `'` to `<p>` and second `'` to `</p>`. Final output would be

```
<p>sample: _4_</p> <p>sample2: _some_</p>
```

Is it possible? I really dont know the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `split` and `join` javascript functions to replace all occurrences in a string (which is actually a `char` array).

Try this:

```
val = val.split("' | '").join("</p> <p>");
val = val.split("'").join("<p>");
val = val.slice(0,-3) + "</p>");  // Replace the last <p> to </p>
```

Comment: Are you sure the string contains **exactly** this: `' | '` ?

Comment: Sir? Can I ask few more questions from you? What if I will do the same thing at `_4_`? I want to replace the first `_` to `<b>` and the second to `</b>`? @KobyDouek

Comment: Replacing the _X_ to <b>X</b> can be a bit tricky, you will need to use a regular expression - look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834072/js-replace-digits-with-regular-expressions. Let me know if you will need more help.

Comment: @duterte I've added an answer to your question on how to also replace `_`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution using `replace` on string with `split` and `join` in combination:

```
val = val.split("' | '").join("<p> </p>");
val = val.replace(/^'/,"<p>").replace(/'$/,"</p>"); // Replaces first "'" with <p> and last "'" with </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str = "'sample: _4_' | 'sample2: _some_'";

var i=0;

for(k=0;k<str.split("'").length+2;k++)
{
str=str.replace("'",function myFunction(){if(i==0) {i=1;return "<p>"; }if  (i==1){i=0;return "</p>";} });
}

str=str.replace("|"," ");
```

Here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/j64u5em6/1/

Answer (score 0):

[You've asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735631/how-to-do-string-replace-in-javascript#comment72589656_42735673) for a way to also replace `_` with `<b>`/`</b>`

```js
var getReplacement = (function() {
  var replacements = {
    "'": {
      i: 0,
      elements: ["<p>", "</p>"]
    },
    "_": {
      i: 0,
      elements: ["<b>", "</b>"]
    }
  };

  return function(match) {
    var replacement = replacements[match];
    if (replacement) {
      return replacement.elements[replacement.i++ % replacement.elements.length];
    } else {
      return match;
    }
  };
}());


var str = "'sample: _4_' | 'sample2: _some_'";

console.log(str.replace(/'|_/g, getReplacement));
```